# jQuery - select option in select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery / Programmatically Select an Option in Select Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573930/jquery-programmatically-select-an-option-in-select-box)

I was wondering, is it possible to select an option from a selectbox/combobox directly from jQuery. For example I want to select the option with the value 5 in a select with values from 1 to 10.

The only solution I can think of is to remove all options and recreate them with the right selected value, but that's a bit unefficient.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery / Programmatically Select an Option in Select Box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573930/jquery-programmatically-select-an-option-in-select-box) and [Most correct way to select option in <select> box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544086/most-correct-way-to-select-option-in-select-box) and [use jquery to select a dropdown option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864620/use-jquery-to-select-a-dropdown-option) and [jQuery Setting an option on a select box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375455/jquery-setting-an-option-on-a-select-box)

Comment: searched for it, but didn't find anything. thanks, the first suggestion did what i wanted.

Comment: `@Eduard:` You can delete this question if you agree it's a duplicate of one of the ones @Felix listed. (Use the "delete" link below it.)

Comment: "jQuery / Programmatically Select an Option in Select Box" didn't come up when you searched for "jQuery select option in select box"??? That's a pretty serious search tool flaw if so.

Comment: "3,161 search results for posts containing `select option in select box` tagged with `jquery`"

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: can't delete it, as it has answers, I flagged it for removal. @ Tomalak: you're off topic, good job, you're a better searcher than me.

Comment: `@Eduard:` Ah, yes, of course. Yet another reason people shouldn't answer questions that clearly have duplicates. :-) Re @Tomalak's comment, he's not a search ninja: When I took the title of your question ("jQuery - select option in select box") and pasted it into the search box here on SO, the second result (your question being the first) was a duplicate of this question. (Don't worry, duplicates happen, but it's worth checking things like that.)

Comment: I mean, I *am* a search ninja, but said search ninja skills were not required in this case. All you have to do is remove two words from that title and you get this one.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Just treat the select box as you would any other input element:

```
$("#MySelectBox").val("5");
```

Answer (score 17):

You can do this by adding the `selected` attribute in `<option>` tag.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn2').click(function(){
        $('#sel1 option[value=2]').attr('selected','selected');
    });
    $('#btn3').click(function(){
        $('#sel1 option[value=3]').attr('selected','selected');
    });
    $('#btn5').click(function(){
        $('#sel1 option[value=5]').attr('selected','selected');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sel1">
    <option value='1'>Option 1</option>
    <option value='2'>Option 2</option>
    <option value='3'>Option 3</option>
    <option value='4'>Option 4</option>
    <option value='5'>Option 5</option>
    <option value='6'>Option 6</option>
    <option value='7'>Option 7</option>
    <option value='8'>Option 8</option>
    <option value='9'>Option 9</option>    
</select>
<input id="btn2" type=button value='Select 2' />
<input id="btn3" type=button value='Select 3' />
<input id="btn5" type=button value='Select 5' />
```

Comment: What is the other value of the selected attribute? I mean there's 'selected', is there 'unselected' or 'false' or anything like that?

Answer (score 8):

Of course you can

Just use this code to select option 5:

```
$("#ComboBox").val(5);
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/ULSS5/)

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is go around setting the attribute `selected` to `true` or `selected`.

```
var arrayOfOptions = $('#mySelect option') //will return an array of options in the order they are found
```

Just iterate over them, something like:

```
for(var i=0; i<arrayOfOptions.length; i++) {
   var opt = arrayOfOptions[i];
   //feel free to check the index of i here if you want to set
   //a particular index to selected or a range.
   //similarly the range can be passed in as a function parameter.
   $(opt).attr('selected','selected');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to select the option with value=5 and mark it selected.  If so, this should be it:

```
$("#selectBox[value='5']").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

This should also work:

```
$("#selectBox").attr('value', 5).attr('selected', 'selected');
```