# How to select a drop-down option based on a value?

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following drop-down:

```
<select id="#test">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Now I am getting a value on `document.ready` like:

```
var res = $('#someotherid').val();
```

which is 1,2 or 3.

Now I want this value automatically set in the drop-down.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399640/jquery-select-option-in-select-box/7399694#7399694

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the selected option with the `val` method too, so after you get the value of whatever `#someotherid` is, you can use it to set the selected option of `#test`:

```
var res= $('#someotherid').val();
$("#test").val(res);
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/kh823/1/).